# Hiding the particular value in php

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am getting a string value in php. It shows all the related lists from the db,  but my question here is about the sidebar. I want to display the related list item from the same table, but it is getting the whole list, even the row which is already displayed on the main body.
So, could you please help me out, to hide the row already shown.

```
$queryy = "SELECT * FROM cate_websites WHERE s = 'approved' ORDER BY rand()"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con1,$queryy);
$allrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($allrows > 0){
    while ($row_result =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $eid = $row_result['cid']; 
        $etitle =$row_result['title'];
        $eimage = $row_result['img1'];
        $edesc = substr($row_result['meta'],0,100);
        $epermalink=$row_result['permalink']; 
        if($epermalink == $_GET['articles']) { 
           echo" here it should not display the get value but it show all the rest of the values";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please use punctuation, the first sentence is very difficult to read.

Comment: OPnly echo the data if the condition is false: `if($epermalink != $_GET['articles']) { 
          //echo here
        }`

Comment: i could not understand what you want to do. Steve suggested != , i think i will help , if not, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you wish to skip the particular link from the list. Correct me if I am wrong.

The query should be like this.

```
$queryy = "SELECT * FROM cate_websites 
WHERE s = 'approved' and permalink!='".$_GET['articles']."' 
ORDER BY rand()";
```

Comment if you feel this is not the answer expected.(Also pls add filters and all as this will be pretty injection prone if used like this)